# Delete duplicate records from a table but keep some dupes so that I can show the changes in values over a period of time

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I am trying to delete duplicate records from a table but I want to keep some dupes so that I can show the changes in values over a period of time. Desired output will explain what I mean. If I use the query below, which I created based on various answers to some of the queries posted on this website, I don't get what I want. I have posted the data in the original table, what I would like my result set to look like, and what I actually get if I use my query.

```
delete FROM 
 (select t.*, rowid, 
 row_number() over  (partition by S_ID,Fld_ID,val order by dt) dup
 from my_t t)
where dup >1 
order by dt;
```

Original table(my_t)

```
dt          Fld_ID  S_ID    Val  
18-Dec-15   1206    1676266 1.4  
31-Dec-15   1206    1676266 1.4  
31-Jan-16   1206    1676266 1.4  
29-Feb-16   1206    1676266 1.4  
17-Mar-16   1206    1676266 1.2  
31-Mar-16   1206    1676266 1.2  
02-Apr-16   1206    1676266 1.2  
03-Apr-16   1206    1676266 1.2  
11-Apr-16   1206    1676266 1.2  
14-Apr-16   1206    1676266 1.4  
16-Apr-16   1206    1676266 1.4  
18-Dec-14   2804    1676266 5955  
30-Dec-15   2804    1676266 5955  
31-Jan-16   2804    1676266 5955  
29-Feb-16   2804    1676266 5955  
17-Mar-16   2804    1676266 6895  
18-Mar-16   2804    1676266 5955  
19-Mar-16   2804    1676266 5955  
20-Mar-16   2804    1676266 8587  
21-Mar-16   2804    1676266 8587  
23-Mar-16   2804    1676266 8587  
24-Mar-16   2804    1676266 8587  
18-Dec-14   2804    1676775 86645  
30-Dec-15   2804    1676775 86645  
31-Jan-16   2804    1676775 86640  
29-Feb-16   2804    1676775 86645  
17-Mar-16   2804    1676775 86645
```

Desired outcome

```
dt          Fld_ID  S_ID    Val  
18-Dec-15   1206    1676266 1.4  
17-Mar-16   1206    1676266 1.2  
14-Apr-16   1206    1676266 1.4  
18-Dec-14   2804    1676266 5955  
17-Mar-16   2804    1676266 6895  
18-Mar-16   2804    1676266 5955  
20-Mar-16   2804    1676266 8587  
18-Dec-14   2804    1676775 86645  
31-Jan-16   2804    1676775 86640  
29-Feb-16   2804    1676775 86645
```

Actual outcome

```
dt          Fld_ID  S_ID    Val  
18-Dec-15   1206    1676266 1.4  
17-Mar-16   1206    1676266 1.2  
18-Dec-14   2804    1676266 5955  
17-Mar-16   2804    1676266 6895  
20-Mar-16   2804    1676266 8587  
18-Dec-14   2804    1676775 86645  
31-Jan-16   2804    1676775 86640
```

Comment: Thanks QSD.  On what criteria do you want to select which duplicates-to-keep?  By date?  Also in you example it looks like you are aiming for up to one duplicate but not more.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep one duplicate around based on the date, the below example is one way to do so.  (This could be adjusted to keep N duplicates or to sort in a different way, or randomly as needed.  There are a couple modifications to show this after the first example).

After creating `MY_T` as in your example, one can delete all duplicates except one (the 2nd-oldest after the original) with the below:

```
DELETE FROM MY_T
WHERE ROWID IN
      (SELECT THE_ROWID
       FROM
         (SELECT
            ROWID           THE_ROWID,
            ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (
              PARTITION BY S_ID, FLD_ID, VAL
              ORDER BY DT ) DUP
          FROM MY_T T)
       WHERE DECODE(DUP, 2, 1, DUP) > 1);


15 rows deleted.
```

Then, query to check the result:

```
SELECT
  DT, FLD_ID, S_ID, VAL
FROM MY_T
ORDER BY 2 ASC, 2 ASC, 4 ASC, 1 ASC;
```

Result:

```
DT         FLD_ID  S_ID     VAL    
17-MAR-16  1206    1676266  1.2    
31-MAR-16  1206    1676266  1.2    
18-DEC-15  1206    1676266  1.4    
31-DEC-15  1206    1676266  1.4    
18-DEC-14  2804    1676266  5955   
30-DEC-15  2804    1676266  5955   
17-MAR-16  2804    1676266  6895   
20-MAR-16  2804    1676266  8587   
21-MAR-16  2804    1676266  8587   
31-JAN-16  2804    1676775  86640  
18-DEC-14  2804    1676775  86645  
30-DEC-15  2804    1676775  86645
```

If you want to keep 2 duplicates instead, change from `DECODE(DUP, 2, 1, DUP) > 1` to `CASE WHEN DUP < 4 THEN 1 ELSE DUP END > 1`.  Now the delete only hits 10 rows:

```
DELETE FROM MY_T
WHERE ROWID IN
      (SELECT THE_ROWID
       FROM
         (SELECT
            ROWID           THE_ROWID,
            ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (
              PARTITION BY S_ID, FLD_ID, VAL
              ORDER BY DT ) DUP
          FROM MY_T T)
       WHERE CASE WHEN DUP < 4 THEN 1 ELSE DUP END > 1);


10 rows deleted.

SELECT
  DT, FLD_ID, S_ID, VAL
FROM MY_T
ORDER BY 2 ASC, 2 ASC, 4 ASC, 1 ASC;

DT         FLD_ID  S_ID     VAL    
17-MAR-16  1206    1676266  1.2    
31-MAR-16  1206    1676266  1.2    
02-APR-16  1206    1676266  1.2    
18-DEC-15  1206    1676266  1.4    
31-DEC-15  1206    1676266  1.4    
31-JAN-16  1206    1676266  1.4    
18-DEC-14  2804    1676266  5955   
30-DEC-15  2804    1676266  5955   
31-JAN-16  2804    1676266  5955   
17-MAR-16  2804    1676266  6895   
20-MAR-16  2804    1676266  8587   
21-MAR-16  2804    1676266  8587   
23-MAR-16  2804    1676266  8587   
31-JAN-16  2804    1676775  86640  
18-DEC-14  2804    1676775  86645  
30-DEC-15  2804    1676775  86645  
29-FEB-16  2804    1676775  86645
```

If you'd like to randomly delete instead of by `DT`, you can change the partitioning sort to `ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM()`:

```
DELETE FROM MY_T
WHERE ROWID IN
      (SELECT THE_ROWID
       FROM
         (SELECT
            ROWID           THE_ROWID,
            ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (
              PARTITION BY S_ID, FLD_ID, VAL
              ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM() ) DUP
          FROM MY_T T)
       WHERE DECODE(DUP, 2, 1, DUP) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I used the query below to achieve what I wanted.

delete from
    (select
   t.*,
   row_number()    over    (partition by S_ID, FLD_ID,val order by DT) dup,
   val - LAG(val, 1, 0) OVER (partition by S_ID, FLD_ID order by DT) as Lag_V
-- decode(val, LAG(val, 1, 0) OVER (partition by S_ID, FLD_ID order by dt),1,0) --as Lag_VC
   from MY_T
  )
where Lag_V= 0  and dup>1;

Note: The LAG_V is for numeric fields whereas the commented decode line in alias LAG_VC can be used for character fields.

Thanks everyone for replying to my question.